# Refresh Data in Access 2016 from Read-Only MySQL ODBC`

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am attempting to "sync" data from a read-only ODBC MySQL server to Access 2016. I need to move the data into Access so that I can more easily manipulate and create better customized reports.

I have linked the data tables between Access and MySQL, however I cannot get the data in these tables to automatically refresh. I must go into Access and hit "Refresh All".

What I'm looking to do is update all of my open tables in Access once nightly so that each morning the data used to build these reports is new. Currently if I leave these tables all evening, when I get in the next morning I must hit "Refresh-All" for Access to go retrieve the most recent data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Have you created **linked** ODBC tables, or have you actually **imported** the data into Access tables?

Comment: You have the Access frontend file opened all night including tables?

Comment: I have created linked ODBC tables.

Comment: I don't know any other way other than keeping the frontend file opened, since the tables are linked, the data is only locally stored anytime I actually open the tables.

Comment: A linked ODBC table is basically a pointer to the datasource. Every time you open such a table, or your report reads it, it retrieves the current data from MySql. I really don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The data in linked tables is automatically refreshed by access when you attempt to read them.  You can do that by displaying a datasheet view of the database, or by a form where the linked table is the data source.  Beware, we have had problems which tables with lots of records being the source for drop down lists, having the database locked.

Access only does this properly (and at speed) if either the underlying table has a unique clustered index, or after having linked the tables you create an index in access.

If you want to create a copy that you can manipulate (such as write to) and the underlying tables are read only, then you will have to create matching unlinked tables and execute some form of copy sql and appropriate points in your application.